# Strange behavior of option binding inside of template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

For some reason i can't select option with null value if select control is defined inside of knockout template, as select immediately changes it's state to default. **Note: it works just fine if select is defined outside.** Just try it:

```js
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.options = [ null, 1, 2, 3];
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable();
    self.onSelectionChange = ko.computed(function(){
        alert(self.selectedOption());
    });
  
    self.items = [{someProp: null, title: "item 1"},
                  {someProp: 2, title: "item 2"},
                  {someProp: 1, title: "item 3"},
                  {someProp: 1, title: "item 4"},
                  {someProp: 3, title: "item 5"}];
                
    self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.items.filter(function(item){
            return item.someProp === self.selectedOption();
        });
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'list-template', data: filteredItems }"></div>

<script id="list-template" type="text/html">
  <select data-bind="options: $root.options,
                       optionsCaption: 'select...',
                       value: $root.selectedOption"></select>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <li data-bind="text: title"></li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

Can anybody explain me why it works like this? Should i understand something or it seems to be knockout issue?

**UPDATE:** This code is just boiled down sample of real one. There is no sense to tell me it is senseless ;)
I just have some records in a table, and some of it's columns have filter by some field. And **I need select could have both underfined and null values**, as undefined means filter is inactive while null means I should show all records which have unset field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout treats undefined, null and the empty string as the same value when writing them to a select.

See writeValue below:

```
ko.selectExtensions = {
    readValue : function(element) {
        switch (ko.utils.tagNameLower(element)) {
            case 'option':
                if (element[hasDomDataExpandoProperty] === true)
                    return ko.utils.domData.get(element, ko.bindingHandlers.options.optionValueDomDataKey);
                return ko.utils.ieVersion <= 7
                    ? (element.getAttributeNode('value') && element.getAttributeNode('value').specified ? element.value : element.text)
                    : element.value;
            case 'select':
                return element.selectedIndex >= 0 ? ko.selectExtensions.readValue(element.options[element.selectedIndex]) : undefined;
            default:
                return element.value;
        }
    },

    writeValue: function(element, value, allowUnset) {
        switch (ko.utils.tagNameLower(element)) {
            case 'option':
                switch(typeof value) {
                    case "string":
                        ko.utils.domData.set(element, ko.bindingHandlers.options.optionValueDomDataKey, undefined);
                        if (hasDomDataExpandoProperty in element) { // IE <= 8 throws errors if you delete non-existent properties from a DOM node
                            delete element[hasDomDataExpandoProperty];
                        }
                        element.value = value;
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Store arbitrary object using DomData
                        ko.utils.domData.set(element, ko.bindingHandlers.options.optionValueDomDataKey, value);
                        element[hasDomDataExpandoProperty] = true;

                        // Special treatment of numbers is just for backward compatibility. KO 1.2.1 wrote numerical values to element.value.
                        element.value = typeof value === "number" ? value : "";
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'select':
                if (value === "" || value === null)       // A blank string or null value will select the caption
                    value = undefined;
                var selection = -1;
                for (var i = 0, n = element.options.length, optionValue; i < n; ++i) {
                    optionValue = ko.selectExtensions.readValue(element.options[i]);
                    // Include special check to handle selecting a caption with a blank string value
                    if (optionValue == value || (optionValue == "" && value === undefined)) {
                        selection = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (allowUnset || selection >= 0 || (value === undefined && element.size > 1)) {
                    element.selectedIndex = selection;
                }
                break;
            default:
                if ((value === null) || (value === undefined))
                    value = "";
                element.value = value;
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

You will have to use a different key than null (-1 is a common choice)

Comment: It clarifies something. Not obvious for me, why it works with null sometimes: https://jsfiddle.net/bh2whpg3/1/. I desided to use selectedOptions binding instead of value binding. Not sure if it is stable workaround, thought.

Comment: It works if the null value is set from the DOM, because readValue does not "normalize" the same way writeValue does. If you set the value observable from the code however, writeValue normalizes it and you end up with undefined as the value.

Answer (score 1):

There are a *lot* of strange things going on in your example, including:

- You have an array of items with each a property called "key", but there are duplicate keys (that's not really a *key* then, is it?);
- You have a `computed` that's posing as an event handler or change subscription;
- You have the `select` inside the template, but it's very unclear why, as it doesn't reference anything of the `$data` in the context;
- The list of `options` and `items` seem to serve the same purpose;
- You initialize the observable with nothing (effectively with `undefined`), though you mean to initialize it with null. However, null is kindof special, and I wouldn't expect KO to behave predictably (for me at least) if you try to make `null` an explicit value. It makes more sense to use an explicit Null Object, which you already have (the first object in `self.items`);

However, without answering your question straight up (which I can't, but someone else might?), I can still offer you in general another way to handle things. Use the entire `item` as your selected item.

Here's an example that works IMO predictably:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.options = [
    { key: null, value: "null item" },
    { key: 1, value: "item 1a" }, 
    { key: 1, value: "item 1b" },
    { key: 2, value: "item 2" }
  ];

  self.selectedOption = ko.observable(self.options[0]);

  self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.options.filter(function(item) {
      return item.key === self.selectedOption().key;
    });
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'list-template', data: filteredItems }"></div>

<script id="list-template" type="text/html">
  <select data-bind="options: $root.options, 
                     optionsText: 'value',
                     value: $root.selectedOption"></select>
  <p>All items with the same key:</p>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <li data-bind="text: value"></li>
  </ul>
</script>

<hr> SelectedOption: <strong data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.selectedOption)"></strong>
```